# Why is HashCode zero for HashMap containing values that are same as keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I noticed that in Java, `hashCode` for `HashMap` that only contain entries where key and values are same, eg `{1:1}`, `{"abc":"abc"}` etc. is always zero. Is there any reasoning behind this odd behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a consequence of the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#hashCode--) of the `hashCode()` for `Map.Entry`, which requires the hash codes of the keys and values to be xor'd.

The only people who could tell you *why* that hash code was chosen are the people who wrote it originally, though my impression is that Java regrets specifying this (bad) hash function.

Comment: I'm afraid to ask how did you learn about this behavior. Answering this question in under a minute is very impressive!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Possibly he'd encountered it and thought about it before (like Jon Skeet's famous Shanghai date discontinuity answer).  Or possibly the first thing he did when seeing the question was to look up the `hashCode` implementation in `HashMap`.  Either way, it's still quite impressive.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight for *someone* who works so much with core libraries; this  should really be "off the shelf"..

Comment: I do indeed know the hashCode implementation of `Map.Entry` off the top of my head.

Comment: FWIW here's "Jon Skeet's famous Shanghai date discontinuity answer": https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/1441122